# Have I made a new limit that tends to $e$?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, fractions

I have made two formulae. One tending to $e$ and one tending to $3$:

$$e = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{2 \times 10^n - 1}{2 \times 10^n - 3}\right)^{10^n - 1}$$

$$3 = \lim_{n \rightarrow (-\infty)} \left(\frac{2 \times 10^n - 1}{2 \times 10^n - 3}\right)^{10^n - 1}$$

Is there a way of proving that these formulae are indeed true? Thanks.

Comment: Recall $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n=e^x$.

Comment: As $n\to\infty$, $10^n\to\infty$, so you can remove the majority of that mess.

Comment: Thanks people. Also thanks to Stephen for editing my question and using the correct size of brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is true because $\lim_{n\to(-\infty)}10^n=0$, so we get 
$$\lim_{n\to(-\infty)}\bigg(\frac{2\times10^n-1}{2\times10^n-3}\bigg)^{10^n-1}=\bigg(\frac{-1}{-3}\bigg)^{-1}=3.$$
For the first one, note that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{2m+1}{2m-1}\bigg)^m=\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{m-1/2}\bigg)^{m-1/2}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{m-1/2}\bigg)^{1/2}.$$
The second bracket goes to $1$ and the first to $e$. Since your sequence is just a subsequence of this one, it has the same limit.

Comment: I believe the two right parentheticals should be $1+\frac{1}{m-1/2}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you :)